# How to Create Multiple Sub Menus In tab Bar Controller in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I want to create tab bar controller which consisting of 4 tab bars and each tab bar should consists of 4 or 5 sub Menus ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of scenario by first putting tab bars below and use libraries like [YSL Container View Controller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/yslcontainerviewcontroller) for sub menu.